# Oracle's OID Service, Oracle.DataAccess and connection strings

Tags: .net, oracle, oid

I am looking to understand how to implement an OID connection string in .Net using the Oracle.DataAccess.dll .

The OID connection string is in this format:
ldap://servname:389/instance,cn=OracleContext

When I use this as my datasource, I receive this error: ..is an invalid connection string attribute

What is the format to connect to Oracle's OID?

Thank you,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being diverted for almost two years, I came back to this issue and sort of have a solution.

First, Oracle notes that ldap support is not supported in the managed library for oracle.  Boo. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbetainstall-1696475.html

Second, using this thread:
[How do I query LDAP from C# to resolve Oracle TNS hostname while using managed ODP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566632/how-do-i-query-ldap-from-c-sharp-to-resolve-oracle-tns-hostname-while-using-mana)

I was able to rig up an ldap lookup for the tns connection string, and ultimately pass that on to nhibernate.

I hope the Oracle eventually supports ldap.

Comment: Your "hope" has been granted - LDAP is now supported by ODP.NET Managed driver - now if I can just figure out how to use it.  ;-)

Comment: It seems to, unless the account you're connecting with is managed in OID :(

Answer (score 10):

Oracle's idea is to configure the LDAP server (OID in your case) in the LDAP.ORA file in the TNS Admin directory (usually $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin). There you have something like:

```
DIRECTORY_SERVERS = (servname:389)
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "dc=company,dc=com"
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

You might also need to adapt the SQLNET.ORA file:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (LDAP, TNSNAMES)
```

Then your connection string is just:

```
Data Source=instance; User ID=scott; Password=tiger
```

(or even without user ID and password).

**Update:**

If you cannot change the TNS Admin directory, the only option I know of is to use connection strings containing all the details (server name, port, SID or service name). There are three formats:

TNS syntax:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=serername)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=instanceSID))); User ID=scott; Password=tiger
```

EZ Connect with a service name (note the single slashe between the server name and the service name):

```
Data Source=//servername:1521/servicename; User ID=scott; Password=tiger
```

EZ Connect with an SID (note the double slashes between the server name and the SID):

```
Data Source=servername:1521//instanceSID; User ID=scott; Password=tiger
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I concur this would work.  In a shared webserver environment, where I can't touch the TNSNAMES file or SQLNET.ORA file, I need to specify via the connection string that I want to hook up to OID.  Is this possible?

Comment: I've never heard of or seen configuration-less connection strings for OID. The only configuration-less connection strings are with TNS syntax or EZ Connect (see above).